# When can I divide both sides of an equation if one side is zero

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quadratics

Where K is some positive Integer

For the following examples:
$$
K(a+b)(p+q)=0
$$
$$
Ka^2+Kbx+Kc=0
$$

Can I just divide both sides of the equation by K (dividing into 0 on the right) and effectively remove K from the equation?

Update
Assuming K could also be negative but never 0 does this still work?

Comment: For equality, you can multiply both sides by the same number (and therefore also divide by any non-zero number since that's just multiplication by the inverse of the number). Whether the number is positive or negative doesn't matter. It does however when you have an inequality because if you multiply by a negative number, you have the inverse the inequality.

Comment: I am specifically concerned with somehow losing information when I divide into 0 because it appears to magically remove a factor on one side without changing the value of 0 on the other. It's a non-invertible operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is given that $K$ is always positive, and an integer, so the least value that $K$ can take on is $1$. You just can't divide when $K = 0$.

Comment: And what about negative, see update to my question?

Answer (score 0):

If $K \neq 0$, multply both sides by $1/K$ gives the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are given:$$K(a+b)(p+q)=0$$You should make use of the [zero product property](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/zero-product-property.html) to then deduce that either:$$K=0\tag{1}$$$$a+b=0\tag{2}$$$$p+q=0\tag{3}$$You can eliminate (1) as your question states that $K$ is some positive integer.